# Adding checkable type annotations with decorators

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Is it possible to have a decorator that adds type annotations to a function such that static type checkers like `mypy` can detect a violation?

As a simple attempt:

```py
@returns(None)
def foo():
    return 3
```

Should be equivalent to:

```py
def foo() -> None:
    return 3
```

However `mypy` cannot detect the type violation when `returns` is defined as

```py
def returns(type):
    def inner(func):
        func.__annotations__['return'] = type
        return func
    return inner
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `func.__annotations__['return'] = type`

Comment: @MZ Yes, I've fixed it, but there is no change to the example.

Comment: `mypy` does *static* type checking, which occurs before the decorator has a chance to run.

Comment: Decorators aren't all that magic; the decorated function is equivalent to `foo = return(None)(foo)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use decorators. `mypy` does *static* type checking, which means all the types have to be available at *compile time*. The decorator adds the annotation at *run time*, which is too late for `mypy` to make use of it.